# Objects still in memory after using custom Java object callbacks

Tags: java, matlab, custom-controls

I have a memory leak kind of a problem.
I'm creating a jLabel object which is wrapped in the MATLAB class.
I'm using the handle for all sets/gets to try prevent problems and memory leaks.

I'm setting the MouseExitedCallback for jLabel using this code. It's a method of the class:

```
function SetMouseExitedCallback (obj, exitcallback)
    set (obj.hLabel, 'MouseExitedCallback', exitcallback)
end
```

This method is called from another class which actually contains the code for MouseExitedCallback.
In that class it is called like this:

```
obj.tooltip.SetMouseExitedCallback (@(src, event)obj.MouseExited);
```

The problem that I'm getting is if I add this last line, if I try to edit files in the project it tells me that jLabel class is still in the memory.
What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First my thought was putting

```
obj.tooltip.SetMouseExitedCallback ('');
```

it in the delete (destructor) method. That didn't work because destructor was never being called. Actually destructor was never called for another class also, the one where actual MouseExited() callback was defined.

What worked at the end is to call:

```
obj.tooltip.SetMouseExitedCallback ('');
```

in the the method which is hiding the tooltip. It is defined in the same class as Mouse Exited() method.
Then after the application is closed VM calls destructors and destroy the object.